# How to correctly write The Little Shop, Le or La and with or without an e?

Tags: traduction, orthographe

When you write The Little Shop in French there seems to be a number of ways to write it. I am wanting to write it as follows 'Le Petite Boutique' but is this incorrect? or should it be La Petite Boutique or even Le Petit Boutique (no e on petit). Please help my head is spinning : )

Comment: For the reference, the title of the musical "Little Shop of Horrors" was translated to "La Petite Boutique des horreurs" into French

Answer (score 2):

As always there must be agreement of the article in gender and in number with the gender and number of the noun; since "boutique" is féminine and in the singular and since the feminine singular article is "la" you should write "La petite boutique". The same principle is applied to adjectives (petite).
If "The Little Shop" is the title of a book or the name of a shop, you keep the upper case letters for the first letter of the title (*La petite boutique*) but you write the whole title in italics.
Independently of this principle of translation, if you want to name as shop in French you can use lower case letters if you prefer; there is no rule for that: the choice is considered to be a matter of style, of personnal taste.

Comment: You observed them but you should also clearly state that capitalization rules differ between English and French.

Comment: There is also the case: "La Petite boutique" respecting the capitalization rules of French.

Comment: @Dimitris I fail to identify the rule you are referring to; what is it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the rule dictates that one should write "La Petite boutique"  (Petite with capital letter; boutique with lower case. But I cannot find the rule here: https://roberge.mus.ulaval.ca/gdrm/03-majus.htm#titres-francais So may be I am missing something:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris There is an error in my answer that you haven't caught (concerning the titles); I'll make that right now.

Comment: @Dimitris You are perhaps confused by this rule: "L'adjectif d'un nom composé ne prend de majuscule que dans les cas suivants :[…] 3/ s’il est le seul élément de caractérisation d’un nom de lieu unique (éléments géographiques, hydrographiques, monuments, etc.) : cap :  le cap Vert, la chapelle Sixtine, le causse Noir, le golfe Persique, les îles Britanniques,  le lac Supérieur, etc.

Comment: Ok. I think you are right. Thanks for the clarification:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Traditionally it would be “La Petite Boutique”: capitalize the first word, the first noun, and also adjectives qualifying the first noun if they come before it. But just capitalizing the first word (even if it's an article) is common nowadays.